# Ближайший слева отрезок, совместимый с jым

Tags: алгоритм

Сортирую отрезки по концам:

```
struct arr {
    double begin, end, weight;
};

bool operator< (arr first, arr second) {
    return first.end < second.end;
}

sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Затем для каждого отрезка нахожу, ближайший слева от него, совместимый с ним.

```
long int binsearch (vector<arr> & vec, double key, long int left, long int right) {
        if (left == right)
            return left;
        long int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if (vec[mid].end > key)
            return binsearch(vec, key, left, mid);
        else
            return binsearch(vec, key, mid+1, right);
}
    p[0]=0;
    for (int i = 1; i != n; ++i) {
        p[i] = binsearch(vec, vec[i].begin, 0, i);
        //cout << p[i] << endl;
    }
```

Не могу понять в чем ошибка.

Comment: В чем именно ошибка, т.е. на каких данных неверный результат?

Comment: @avp Тесты, на которых выдает ошибку закрыты, но я пробовал разные варианты, и выдает верно, мне кажется, я не всегда правильно нахожу ближайший отрезок к j слева от j.

Comment: Не работает сортировка, не могу понять почему. Есть перегруженный оператор, но std::sort, не сортирует.

Comment: Поправил, теперь все ок, но есть проблема с условием остановки рекурсии в бинпоиске. Нужно правильное условие

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, у Вас проблема с равными ключами.

Ну, напишите:

```
 if (left >= right)
   return MIN(left, right);
```

тогда-то уж точно завершиться.